# my fancybox does not show up at all

Tags: html, css, fancybox

HTML:

```
<!--gallery-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        !window.jQuery && document.write('<script src="jquery-1.4.3.min.js"><\/script>');
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.4.pack.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css" media="screen" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="gallery.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("a[rel=example_group]").fancybox({
                'transitionIn'      : 'none',
                'transitionOut'     : 'none',
                'titlePosition'     : 'over',
                'titleFormat'       : function(title, currentArray, currentIndex, currentOpts) {
                    return '<span id="fancybox-title-over">Image ' + (currentIndex + 1) + ' / ' + currentArray.length + (title.length ? ' &nbsp; ' + title : '') + '</span>';
                }
            });
        });
    </script>

<a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="/images/climb.jpg"><img src="climb_s.jpg" alt="climbing" /></a>
<a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="/images/minig.jpg"><img src="minig_s.jpg" alt="minigolf" /></a>
<a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="/images/wake.jpg"><img src="wake_s.jpg" alt="surfing" /></a>
```

CSS:

```
/*lightbox*/

.gallery a img {
    outline: none;
    border: 1px solid #BBB;
    padding: 2px;
    margin-left: 200px;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Nothing is showing up.

Comment: Can you please provide a link.

Comment: file:///G:/Stevenson/Web%202/308_vaca_loan/activities.html

Comment: That link is local to your computer. Do you have it online somewhere?

Comment: its isnt a real site? im making it for class

Answer (score 1):

You have set `rel="group"` in your links but you are binding fancybox to elements with `rel="example_group"` attribute.

Bind fancybox to the proper elements :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a[rel=group]").fancybox({
        'transitionIn'      : 'none',
        'transitionOut'     : 'none',
        'titlePosition'     : 'over',
        'titleFormat'       : function(title, currentArray, currentIndex, currentOpts) {
             return '<span id="fancybox-title-over">Image ' + (currentIndex + 1) + ' / ' + currentArray.length + (title.length ? ' &nbsp; ' + title : '') + '</span>';
        }
    });
});
```